# FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP not working from Notification Section

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I've got a simple use case. I have activity open like below:
`A > B > C`

Now, I get a push notification.

I do the following in my `GCMIntentService` class:

In `onMessage`,

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, A.class);       
PendingIntent contentIntent = 
PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0, notificationIntent,     
PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
notification.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );
```

My expectation is that activities `B, C` should be removed from `Activity stack` and you should be re-directed to activity `A`.

What is happening is, however, `A` gets opened; but when you hit back button I get `C, B, A` again in that order!!

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Here are the things I tried:

1. I've experimented with 
   `notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);`,
   `notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);`
2. I've kept a static reference to the last foreground activity and passed that as `context`.

Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Hi can u share your email id?

Comment: @ArunAntoney: ranjjose@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It may help you. Let me know once you have tested it.

```
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(notificationIntent);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the solution you provided didn't work. Resulted in the same behavior!

Comment: @ranjjose can you try with those flags, but add them to the `notificationIntent` BEFORE you create the `PendingIntent`

Comment: Thanks @LordRaydenMK. The order was also the issue. Infact I added  `notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);` as suggested by @Arun Antoney and then changed the order as suggested by @LordRaydenMK. It worked! Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

try this **[Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)**

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Comment: thanks; but as I've mentioned in the things I've already tried section, I've tried ` notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);`. Moreover I developed push notification refering to the same blog. :)

Comment: We all are using the same method ,please test this in your app once again.

Answer (score 1):

Set launch mode of your activity to "singleTask":

```
<activity
  android:name=".ActivityA"
  android:launchMode="singleTask"
>
```

And set flags as below:

```
Intent intent= new Intent(currentActivity, ActivityA.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```